# Non-deterministic output of simple C program

Tags: c, output, primes, non-deterministic

This is an unfinished program I'm writing to learn C (only checks multiples of 2 currently...)

Ultimately, I want this to be an implementation of the Sieve of Eratosthenes (prime numbers)

The problem I'm having is that the output is non-deterministic: sometimes the output includes 11, other times it does not - This happens for a handful of numbers. I have experimented by changing a few things, such as actually initializing the array of booleans to false.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        int n = atoi(argv[1]);
        int initialPrimeIterator = 2;
        _Bool compositePrimeNumbers[n];

        printf("Prime Numbers from 2 -> %d\n", n);
        for (int i = initialPrimeIterator; i < n; i += initialPrimeIterator) {
                compositePrimeNumbers[i-1] = true;
        }
        printf("Done...\n");
        
        printf("Printing prime numbers from 2-> %d\n", n);
        for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
                if (!compositePrimeNumbers[i]){
                        printf("%d\n", i + 1);
                }
        }
        
        return 0;
}
```

edit: haha. Just realized I have an array named 'compositePrime...' Should just be 'compositeNumbers'

Comment: `_Bool compositePrimeNumbers[n];` is uninitialized for numbers which are not multiples of `initialPrimeIterator` (`i += initialPrimeIterator`).

Comment: Please don't include line-numbers in code. If you want to point out a specific line then mention it in the question itself and add a comment on that line.

Comment: A couple of other unrelated points: The `<stdbool.h>` header defines the type `bool`. And you should always check `argc` before using any element in `argv`.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a treasure-hunt, or do you think you could perhaps supply the inputs for which the outputs are a surprise?

Comment: You might want to explain your first loop to a [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) or suitable substitute (roommate, friend, etc.). All it does is mark all odd indexes as `true`.

Comment: I have tried initializing all the booleans to false. It still resulted in non-deterministic output.


Sorry for the line numbers.

Yeah, I saw that stdbool.h has an alias for bool instead of _Bool, thanks.

Not treasure hunt - used input "100"

First loop is just the first case of Sieve of Erathosthenes - initially it will find all multiples of 2.  Subsequently it will be further developed to continue marking the multiples of the next prime number which is found by the lowest-index 'false' boolean that is greater than the current prime number we are iterating on

Comment: Could you add your updated code to the question? There must still be a problem with the initialization.

Comment: I tried adding the initialization to false for the boolean array again and it seemed to solve the problem. I must have messed something up intitially

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I understand you are aiming at completing the program when overcoming this hurdle, I will not post a completed program, but only point out issues in your current version:

1. As it has been noted, the array `compositePrimeNumbers` is uninitialized. Since it must be initialized with all values `false` which is represented by `0`, the quickest way is this:

```
     memset(compositePrimeNumbers, 0, sizeof(compositePrimeNumbers));
```

2. You should not mark the current `initialPrimeIterator` as a composite number, hence the for-loop should start with the next multiple. Also, `n` must be included:

```
    for (int i = 2 * initialPrimeIterator; i <= n; i += initialPrimeIterator) {
```

(actually, this can be optimized by replacing `2 * initialPrimeIterator` with `initialPrimeIterator * initialPrimeIterator`).

With these changes, I believe you are well on the way to complete the program.

Answer (score 2):

In C, a local array is not initialized, probably for performance reasons.

One way to fix this is to loop over it to set each element to `false`.

Comment: I tried this and still got the same non-deterministic output

Comment: _"probably for performance reasons"_: you can drop the word "probably".